# ColdFusion CFDOCUMENT with links to other PDFs

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, itext, cfdocument

I am creating a PDF using the cfdocument tag at the moment. The PDF is not much more than a bunch of links to other PDFs.

So I create this PDF index and the links are all HREFs

```
<a href="Another_PDF.pdf">Another PDF</a>
```

if I set the localURL attribute to "no" my URLs have the whole web path in them:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/media/PDF/Another_PDF.pdf">Another PDF</a>
```

if I set the localURL attribute to "yes" then I get:

```
<a href="File:/D:/website/media/PDF/Another_PDF.pdf">Another PDF</a>
```

So this index PDF is going to go onto a CD and all of the linked PDFs are going to sit right next to it so I need a relative link ... more like:

```
<a href="Another_PDF.pdf">Another PDF</a>
```

cfdocument does not seem to do this. I can modify the file name of the document and make it "File:///Another_PDF.pdf" but this does not work either because I don't know the driveletter of the CD drive ... or if the files are going to end up inside a directory on the CD.

Is there a way (possibly using iText or something) of opening up the PDF once it is created and converting the URL links to actual PDF GoTo tags?

I know this is kind of a stretch but I am at my wits end with this.

So I've managed to get into the Objects but I'm still struggling with.

Converting from:

```
5 0 obj<</C[0 0 1]/Border[0 0 0]/A<</URI(File:///75110_002.PDF)/S/URI>>/Subtype/Link/Rect[145 502 184 513]>>endobj
```

To this:

```
19 0 obj<</SGoToR/D[0/XYZ null null 0]/F(75110_002.PDF)>>endobj 
20 0 obj<</Subtype/Link/Rect[145 502 184 513]/Border[0 0 0]/A 19 0 R>>endobj
```

Wow this is really kicking my ass! :)

So I've managed to get the document open, loop through the Link Annotations, capture the Rect co-ordinates and the linked to document name (saved into an array of Structures) and then successfully deleted the Annotation which was a URI Link.

So now I thought I could now loop over that array of structures and put the Annotations back into the document using the createLink method or the setAction method. But all the examples I've seen of these methods are attached to a Chunk (of text). But my document already has the Text in place so I don't need to remake the text links I just need to put the Links back in in the same spot.

So I figured I could reopen the document and look for the actual text that was the link and then attache the setAction to th ealready existing chunk of text .... I can't find the text!!

I suck! :)

Comment: Is the CD directory structure known/always the same?

Comment: It's not ... or ideally it should be able to be dynamic. Right now I am looking at a CD that has all of the PDFs (including the index) inside a directory called "STD_FLD" so the path on my computer is J:\STD_FLD because my CD drive is my J drive.

Comment: The index PDF really should be relative to itself. You should be able to drag all of the PDFs off of the CD and store them anywhere and the links should still work.

Comment: I do not think it's possible.  Please read this: **<http://stackoverflow.com/a/15193744/3112803>**

Comment: Yes I know how URI schemes work I am more interested in converting the URI links in the PDF with GoToR links. Hopefully using iText.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8141831) has an example of updating the link actions, by modifying the pdf's annotations. It is for iTextSharp 5.x, but aside from the package names, the java code is not that much different.

Comment: I'm so close!! I can get to the Onjects in question but I am still not finding a way to convert from one type of link to another:

Comment: You have to grab the URI key from your PDFAction object. It returns a string. Then replace the string for the URI key. It is just like replacing a value in a structure.  ie `theActionObject.put( pdfName.URI, "theNewValueHere");`

Comment: I've ordered the book by Bruno Lowagie and hopefully it'll be in the office today!! Fingers crossed this will help me with changing URI links to GoToR links and I can flag @Leigh as the answer below!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it:

```
public function resetLinks( string source, string destination) {

    try {

        // initialize objects
        Local.reader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( arguments.source );
        Local.pdfName = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfName");
        Local.annot = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation");
        Local.out = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init( arguments.destination );
        Local.stamper = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper").init(Local.reader, Local.out);
        Local.PdfAction = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfAction");
        Local.PdfRect = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Rectangle");
        Local.PdfBorderArray = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfBorderArray").init(javacast("float", "0"), javacast("float", "0"), javacast("float", "0"));
        Local.newAnnots = [];

        // check each page for hyperlinks
        // Save the data to a structure then write it to an array 
        // then delete the hyperlink Annotation
        for ( Local.i = 1; Local.i <= Local.reader.getNumberOfPages(); Local.i = Local.i + 1) {
            //Get all of the annotations for the current page
            Local.page = Local.reader.getPageN( Local.i );
            Local.annotations = Local.page.getAsArray( Local.PdfName.ANNOTS ).getArrayList();

            // search annotations for links
            for (Local.x = arrayLen(Local.annotations); !isNull( Local.annotations) && Local.x > 0; Local.x--) {
                // get current properties
                Local.current     = Local.annotations[ Local.x ]; 
                Local.dictionary  = Local.reader.getPdfObject( Local.current );
                Local.subType     = Local.dictionary.get( Local.PdfName.SUBTYPE );
                Local.action      = Local.dictionary.get( Local.PdfName.A );
                Local.hasLink     = true;

                //Skip this item if it does not have a link AND action
                if (Local.subType != Local.PdfName.LINK || isNull(Local.action)) {
                    Local.hasLink = false;
                }
                //Skip this item if it does not have a URI
                if ( Local.hasLink && Local.action.get( Local.PdfName.S ) != Local.PdfName.URI ) {
                    Local.hasLink = false;
                } 

                //If it is a valid URI, update link
                if (Local.hasLink) {
                    // extract file name from URL
                    Local.oldLink = Local.action.get( Local.pdfName.URI );
                    Local.newLink  = getFileFromPath( Local.oldLink );
                    Local.Rect = Local.dictionary.Get(PdfName.Rect);
                    arrayStruct = StructNew();
                    arrayStruct.rectSTR = Local.Rect.toString();
                    arrayStruct.link = Local.newLink;
                    arrayStruct.page = Local.i;
                    ArrayAppend(Local.newAnnots, arrayStruct);
                    // Delete
                    Local.annotations.remove(Local.current);
                }
            }

        }

        // Now really remove them!   
        Local.reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();

        // Now loop over the saved annotations and put them back!!
        for ( Local.z = 1; Local.z <= ArrayLen(Local.newAnnots); Local.z++) {
            // Parse the rect we got save into an Array
            theRectArray = ListToArray(ReplaceNoCase(ReplaceNoCase(Local.newAnnots[z].rectSTR, "[", ""), "]", ""));
            // Create the GoToR action
            theAction = Local.PdfAction.gotoRemotePage(javacast("string", '#Local.newAnnots[z].link#'), javacast("string", '#Local.newAnnots[z].link#'), javacast("boolean", "false"), javacast("boolean", "false"));
            // Create the Link Annotation with the above Action and the Rect
            theAnnot = Local.annot.createLink(Local.stamper.getWriter(), Local.PdfRect.init(javacast("int", theRectArray[1]), javacast("int", theRectArray[2]), javacast("int", theRectArray[3]), javacast("int", theRectArray[4])), Local.annot.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, theAction);
            // Remove the border the underlying underlined text will flag item as a link
            theAnnot.setBorder(Local.PdfBorderArray);
            // Add the Annotation to the Page
            Local.stamper.addAnnotation(theAnnot, Local.newAnnots[z].page);
        }
    }

    finally {
        // cleanup
        if (structKeyExists(Local, "reader")) { Local.reader.close(); }
        if (structKeyExists(Local, "stamper")) { Local.stamper.close(); }
        if (structKeyExists(Local, "out")) { Local.out.close(); }
    }
}
```

I couldn't have done this without the help of Leigh!!

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8141831) has an example of updating the link actions, by modifying the pdf annotations. It is written in iTextSharp 5.x, but the java code is not much different.

The thread provides a solid explanation of how annotations work. But to summarize, you need to read in your source pdf and loop through the individual pages for annotations. Extract the links and use something like `getFileFromPath()` to replace them with a file name only.

I was curious, so I did a quick and ugly conversion of the iTextSharp code above. Disclaimer, it is not highly tested:

```
/**
    Usage:

    util = createObject("component", "path.to.ThisComponent");
    util.fixLinks( "c:/path/to/sourceFile.pdf", "c:/path/to/newFile.pdf");

*/
component {

    /**
        Convert all absolute links, in the given pdf, to relative links (file name only)
        @source - absolute path to the source pdf file
        @destination - absolute path to save copy
    */
    public function fixLinks( string source, string destination) {
        // initialize objects
        Local.reader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( arguments.source );
        Local.pdfName = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfName");

        // check each page for hyperlinks
        for ( Local.i = 1; Local.i <= Local.reader.getNumberOfPages(); Local.i++) {

            //Get all of the annotations for the current page
            Local.page = Local.reader.getPageN( Local.i );
            Local.annotations = Local.page.getAsArray( Local.PdfName.ANNOTS ).getArrayList();

            // search annotations for links
            for (Local.x = 1; !isNull( Local.annotations) && Local.x < arrayLen(Local.annotations); Local.x++) {

                  // get current properties
                  Local.current     = Local.annotations[ Local.x ]; 
                  Local.dictionary  = Local.reader.getPdfObject( Local.current );
                  Local.subType     = Local.dictionary.get( Local.PdfName.SUBTYPE );
                  Local.action      = Local.dictionary.get( Local.PdfName.A );
                  Local.hasLink     = true;

                  //Skip this item if it does not have a link AND action
                  if (Local.subType != Local.PdfName.LINK || isNull(Local.action)) {
                       Local.hasLink = false;
                  }
                  //Skip this item if it does not have a URI
                  if ( Local.hasLink && Local.action.get( Local.PdfName.S ) != Local.PdfName.URI ) {
                       Local.hasLink = false;
                  } 

                  //If it is a valid URI, update link
                  if (Local.hasLink) {
                      // extract file name from URL
                      Local.oldLink = Local.action.get( Local.pdfName.URI );
                      Local.newLink  = getFileFromPath( Local.oldLink );

                      // replace link
                      // WriteDump("Changed link from ["& Local.oldLink &"] ==> ["& Local.newLink &"]");
                      Local.pdfString = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfString");
                      Local.action.put( Local.pdfName.URI, Local.pdfString.init( Local.newLink ) );
                  }
            }

        }

        // save all pages to new file   
        copyPDF( Local.reader , arguments.destination );    
    }

    /**
        Copy all pages in pdfReader to the given destination file
        @pdfReader - pdf to copy
        @destination - absolute path to save copy
    */
    public function copyPDF( any pdfReader, string destination) {
        try {

          Local.doc = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Document").init();
          Local.out = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init( arguments.destination );
          Local.writer = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopy").init(Local.doc, Local.out);

          // open document and save individual pages        
          Local.doc.open();
          for (Local.i = 1; i <= arguments.pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); Local.i++) {
              Local.writer.addPage( Local.writer.getImportedPage( arguments.pdfReader,  Local.i) );
          }
          Local.doc.close();
        }
        finally 
        {
            // cleanup
            if (structKeyExists(Local, "doc")) { Local.doc.close(); }
            if (structKeyExists(Local, "writer")) { Local.writer.close(); }
            if (structKeyExists(Local, "out")) { Local.out.close(); }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Leigh Thanks so much. I'm going to try your code right now. It will afford me th eability to edit the path in teh URI. I'm not sure if I edit it from "File:///75110_002.PDF" to just "75110_002.PDF" if the hyperlink will work. My ultimate goal is to change the Annotation's Action Dictionary's "S" key from URI to GoToR. I am not sure if that is even possible. Because the Keys for the URI and the GoToR Annotation are completely different.

Comment: Just so you know that code worked like a champ! So now the TOC PDF sitting in a directory on my desktop or burned onto a CD will open every linked to PDF in a web browser because it is still a URI! :)

Comment: Of course i've gone in and commented out this  `Local.action.put( Local.pdfName.URI, Local.pdfString.init( Local.newLink ) );`  and added `Local.action.put( Local.pdfName.S, Local.pdfString.init( '/GoToR' ) );`  and `Local.action.put( Local.pdfName.D, Local.pdfString.init( '[0, /XYZ, null, null, 0]' ) );`  and `Local.action.put( Local.pdfName.F, Local.pdfString.init( Local.newLink ) );`  and `Local.action.remove( Local.pdfName.URI );`  and it is completely broken!! :)

Comment: I cannot test it now. However, looking at [the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAction.java.html) suggests there are several PDFAction constructors customized for `GoToR`. Try create a new PdfAction then replacing the existing one in the dictionary.

Comment: That is what I'm gonna try today and the trick for me is getting the RECT stuff correct ... most code I see to do this is creating a chunk and then attaching the PDFAction to it ... but I've already got the chunk! Looking forward to Bruno's book!! I would have much rather spent $60 on beer!