# relative path to absolute with file:// protocol

Tags: javascript, html, path

I do scraping on a site which has similar html

`<a href="/pages/1></a>`

I also have the `window.location` object, where I have

```
origin:"http://www.example.org"
```

so I can build the absolute path like `origin + href` = http://www.example.org/pages/1

I made a mockup of the page on my file system for testing.

```
-www.example.org
  |-2017
    |-pages
      |-1.html
      |-2.html
  |-2016
    |-pages
      |-1.html
      |-2.html
```

in those html files the links look something like this:

`<!-- www.example.org/2016/pages/1.html -->
<a href="../../2017/pages/1.html">2017</a>`

In the test the same code won't work, because the window.location object's origin is `file://`:

```
hash:""
host:""
hostname:""
href:"file:///home/me/projects/fp/src/test/fixtures/www.example.org/2016/pages/1.html"
origin:"file://"
pathname:"/home/me/projects/fp/src/test/fixtures/www.example.org/2016/pages/1.html"
port:""
protocol:"file:"
```

which produces `origin + href` = file://../../2017/pages/1.html . With some string manipulation I could make `file:///home/me/projects/fp/src/test/fixtures/www.example.org/2017/pages/1.html` from `location.pathname` if the protocol is `file:` . But is it the right way to handle this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Uri Scheme and Relative Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857416/file-uri-scheme-and-relative-files)

Answer (score 1):

`file://` can be used only for absolute paths.

Only relative path that works is the current working directory.