# List projects/branches/trunks of SVN from command line

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN. I've deployed it on an Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS server, created repositories using the `svnadmin create MyRepo` command and shared projects from Eclipse into the repos.

I can see the projects within a repo from the browser at http://servername/svn/MyRepo/trunk/ or from the CLI using `svn info http://servername/svn/MyRepo/trunk/`. However, this requires me to type the userid/password.

So, how do I list all projects within a repo using the CLI?

Comment: If you have access to the file-system where the repository is located you should be able to just use that directory as `file://` protocol instead of the http(s) URL in `svn info`.

Comment: Ah! Great! One tiny thing: It works with svn list file://home/svn/MyRepo/trunk i.e. the qualified path. Can I use relative path? i.e. when in the /home/svn directory, what should I give for file:??/MyRepo/trunk/ ?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465391/relative-path-to-absolute-with-file-protocol the file: protocol is for absolute paths only. Ok, can live with it.