# Java - How to format file URLs

Tags: java

I would like to know how to make a relative file URL, for example:

```
assets/images/icon.png
```

When I try to enter that in as a file URL, it doesn't work.

What I want to do is use this is an environment such as:

```
new File("path/to/file")
```

The reason I am not giving code, is because I want to know how to do this ***under almost any circumstances***.

Comment: Good news! `new File("path/to/file")` is **correct**.

Comment: this will only work when the url to the file is relative to your program source file

Comment: @javafan No. Relative to where your program is ***started***.

Comment: Google the terms "relative" and "absolute" file path to learn more. Essentially, absolute refers to a full URL in the system. Relative refers to a URL relative to basically the runtime environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code seems correct, the path will be relative. It may depend on your system if `/` is the correct separator, you may also need `//` instead of `/` but that is another story.

---

The easy and up-to-date answer: **Don't use** `File` at all.

The new I/O library of Java (**NIO**) is able to do all that for you, **platform independent**. It revolves around the classes [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

You create a path to your file by using:

```
Paths.get("path", "to", "file");
```

It will **dynamically** select the **correct separators** for your current system.

And you read it using methods from `Files`. For example a demo listing all contents of that file:

```
Path theFile = Paths.get("path", "to", "file");
Files.lines(theFile).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you later need to use older methods which require a `File` object you can simply use the `Path#toFile` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile--)).

---

Note that a **relative path** will always be relative to where your program has started. You can always check where you currently are by using:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: `File` isn't quite as platform dependent as you suggest (since it's not actually tied to the real file-system), you can also do `System.out.println(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "abc.txt").getCanonicalPath());`

Comment: I am aware of this but its good that you highlight it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are really asking about `File` objects or `"file:"` URLs.  They are different things.

If you are talking about `File` objects, then the good news is that relative `File` objects are supported, and that `new File("path/to/file")` is valid.  (Actually, it is valid irrespective of whether it resolves.)

If you are concerned about creating `File` objects in a way that works for all platforms, you can be assured that pathname syntax with forward slashes is understood by `File` ... even on a Windows machine.

For new code, you have the alternative of using `java.nio.file.Path` which has a richer API.  But either `File` or `Path` can assemble a path programmatically from simple names, so you can often avoid dubious "string bashing" code to build paths,

---

If you are talking about `"file:"` URLs / URIs, the bad news is that relative `"file:"` URLs are not allowed.  Specifically the W3C spec for the `"file:"` URI scheme requires the path of a `"file:"` URL/URI to have a root.  For example:

```
 file:path/to/file
```

is not valid. For more details:

- [File Uri Scheme and Relative Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857416/file-uri-scheme-and-relative-files)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Now you can have a relative URI.  But this is just a "path" and has to be resolved relative to some other URL.