# Opening local HTML file using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is it possible to open a local HTML file with headless Chrome using Puppeteer (without a web server)? I could only get it to work against a local server.

I found `setContent()` and `goto()` in the [Puppeteer API documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options), but:

1. `page.goto`: did not work with a local file or `file://`.
2. `page.setContent`: is for an HTML string

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I just did a test locally (you can see I did this on windows) and puppeteer happily opened my local html file using page.goto and a full file url, and saved it as a pdf:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');    
(async() => {    
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();    
await page.goto('file://C:/Users/compoundeye/test.html');    
await page.pdf({
  path: 'test.pdf',
  format: 'A4',
  margin: {
        top: "20px",
        left: "20px",
        right: "20px",
        bottom: "20px"
  }    
});    
await browser.close();    
})();
```

If you need to use a relative path might want to look at this question about the use of relative file paths: [File Uri Scheme and Relative Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857416/file-uri-scheme-and-relative-files)

Comment: It looks much nicer with `await page.goto(\`file:${path.join(__dirname, 'test.html')}\`);`

Comment: if you're a Node.js noob like me, don't forget to define path before: `const path = require('path');`

Comment: If you're a Node.js noob like me, but you are using new es6 features in your project
`import * as path from 'path'` 

[trying to be fun and make the world happier :)]

Answer (score 56):

If file is on local, using setContent will be better than goto

```
var contentHtml = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/compoundeye/test.html', 'utf8');
await page.setContent(contentHtml);
```

You can check performance between **setContent** and **goto** at [here](https://dev.to/chuongtrh/improve-performance-generate-pdf-using-puppeteer-4lg7)

Comment: While **setContent** is faster than **goto**, I find that `waitUntil: 'networkidle2'` will make setContent take twice as long as goto with `waitUntil: 'networkidle2'` option.

Answer (score 14):

Let's take a screenshot of an element from a local HTML file as an example.

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';


(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    //  __dirname is a global node variable that corresponds to the absolute 
    // path of the folder containing the currently executing file
    await page.goto(`file://${__dirname}/pages/test.html`);

    const element = await page.$('.myElement');

    if (element) {
        await element.screenshot({
            path: `./out/screenshot.png`,
            omitBackground: true,
        });
    }

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I had to remove : omitBackground: true

Answer (score 8):

Navigation to local files only works if you also pass a referer of `file://`, otherwise security restrictions prevent this from succeeding.

Answer (score 6):

Why not open the HTML file read the content, then "setContent"

Comment: Other way
```javascript
await page.goto(`data:text/html,${pageHtml}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
```

Comment: Using ```page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`)``` led to some issues with special characters for us, setContent is definitely a better solution!  duo to [this post](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/907#issuecomment-472334126)

Answer (score 4):

I open the file I wanted to load into the browser and copied the URL to make sure all the \'s where correct.

```
await page.goto(`file:///C:/pup_scrapper/testpage/TM.html`);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `file-url` to prepare the URL to pass to `page.goto`:

```js
const fileUrl = require('file-url');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');    

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();   
 
await page.goto(fileUrl('file.html'));    
 
await browser.close();
```