# Opening a local file with local references with puppeteer-firefox

Tags: firefox, puppeteer, firefox-headless

This is a similar question to [Opening local html file using puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587352/opening-local-html-file-using-puppeteer), except that that one is using regular Puppeteer (headless Chrome) and this one is using [the Firefox version](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/tree/master/experimental/puppeteer-firefox), and I care about references to other local files.

I'm trying to open a local HTML file with puppeteer-firefox. Here's some example code:

```
const pptrFirefox = require('puppeteer-firefox');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
  const browser = await pptrFirefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`file:${path.join(__dirname, 'template.html')}`);
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

This hangs at the page.screenshot line.

I've tried this with `file:` and `file://` as the prefix of the path. It's the same either way.

It works fine if the URL is something remote like `https://example.com` instead.

My first idea for a workaround was to get a string of the HTML I want, by using a templating library or just `readFile`, and then passing this to `page.setContent`. This works, but then the page won't load its assets such as relative paths to local image files. I've tried prefixing those asset paths with the full `file:` path; no difference.

I swapped out puppeteer-firefox for the regular puppeteer, and it works.

Will headless Firefox simply refuse to load local files? Or am I doing something wrong? Or is there a bug in puppeteer-firefox?

Comment: In your `page.goto` line, you are missing a closing bracket `}`. Apart from that, your code is working fine for me (Windows).

Comment: I think my comment got missing :/ That feature is still failing in Firefox, see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/1623bef26452f5f90c899ca159f237e074c765b0/test/network.spec.js#L706, You'll have to wait for it.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf that was a typo for my example code which doesn't exist in my application; sorry about that. You say it's working for you on Windows? You're definitely using the Firefox version of puppeteer?

Comment: @hardkoded: I don't fully understand the code you linked. Are you saying the feature isn't complete yet? I expected to see something on https://aslushnikov.github.io/ispuppeteerfirefoxready/ but I don't see where this feature would be.

Comment: @tremby Sorry, I was wrong. `page.screenshot` is not working for me. The browser opens and navigates to the file (I checked it in headful mode), but it is actually stuck when `page.screenshot` is called.