# Relative file path for json schemas in VS Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

Is there any way to use a relative file path for JSON schemas ?

Below mentioned syntax not work in vscode **:**

```
$schema = "file:///foo.schema.json"
```

And this one works **:**

```
$schema = "file:///c:/test/foo.schema.json"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a scheme like `file:`, that forms a full (absolute) URI, instead of a (relative) URI Reference.

A full URI is supposed to mean the same thing everywhere, so it doesn't make sense to have a relative file path. Also note that `file:///foo.schema.json` is the same thing as `file://localhost/foo.schema.json`

To write a relative filename, use a URI Reference, like `foo.schema.json`. This will be resolved against a *URI base* — typically the URI of the document — to form the correct URI, even if the file moves on the filesystem.

For example, if you use this in a file at `c:\test\main.json`, then the Base URI will be `file:///c:/test/main.json`, and the URI Reference will resolve to `file:///c:/test/foo.schema.json`, which is correct.

See [File Uri Scheme and Relative Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857416/file-uri-scheme-and-relative-files) for more information on this.