# Storyshots doesn't work on local storybook-static folder

Tags: html, storybook, jest-puppeteer, storybook-addon, storyshots

## Problem Summary

Storybook snapshot test on static storybook returning **blank screenshots** even though they look fine on `localhost:8080` when I ran `npx http-server storybook-static`

### Tech stack and relevant code

- Vue 3
- Vite
- Storybook
- Jest
- Storyshots
- Puppeteer

I have components and their respective stories. `npm run storybook` works perfectly fine. My `storybook.spec.js` is as follows:

```js
import { imageSnapshot } from "@storybook/addon-storyshots-puppeteer"

import initStoryshots from "@storybook/addon-storyshots"


initStoryshots({
    suite: "Image storyshots", 
    test: imageSnapshot(
        storybookUrl: 'file://absolute/path/to/my/storybook-static'
    )
})
```

I ran the following. fyi, I did not modify any file in storybook-static after running `npm run build-storybook`.

```bash
npm run build-storybook
npm run test
```

`npm run test` constitutes `jest --config=jest.config.js test`

### Problem

Unfortunately, the screenshots I get are all blank and fail the snapshot test.

I suspect it might be due to a CORS error just like other Storybook users when they click `<project-root>/storybook-static/index.html` after running `npm run build-storybook`, to which I want to ask for a solution as well, because I wanna run test remotely on a headless server.

### Note

I used absolute path because relative path caused a resource not found error during the testing process.

Answer (score 2):

None of the images were loading within my pipeline but worked fine locally, ended up being because the components were fetching images using a relative path `<img src="/my-image" />` which apparently is not allowed using the [file protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857416/file-uri-scheme-and-relative-files).

I ended up doing 2 things:

1. Updating the static dirs directory to use the root  by updating the main.js file in storybook

```
module.exports = {
 staticDirs: [{ from: '../static', to: '/' }],
}
```

2. Added a script to remove the leading slash of images in the preview-head.html file from storybook

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach((img) => {
        const original = img.getAttribute('src');
        img.setAttribute('src', original.replace('/', ''));
      });
  });
</script>
```

Another (arguably better) approach would be to run the tests through a server where you can access the images

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're running the tests from `file://` instead of `http://`. So the `URI` is `file://` and the img url ends up like this after applying some url logic: `path.resolve(window.location, '/your-image.png')` `file:///your-image.png`.
If this is the case you could change to `http://`. You can start a express server and serve the `storybook-static` folder from `setupGlobal` and then shut it down in `teardownGlobal`. Then you will need to change your `storybookUrl` to `http://localhost:<some-port>`.