# Path part of "filename.m4v" is "/private/tmp", which is unexpected

Tags: swift, nsurl

I'm writing some Swift code to parse filenames of video files and extract the show, season and episode. These are returned as key/value parts in a dictionary. As part of my unit tests, I found something odd. First the code (comments and whitespace removed):

```
public static func parse(_ filename: String, defaults: [String: String] = [String: String]()) -> [String: String] {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filename)
    let file = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    if file.count == 0 {
        return ret
    }
    if file.count > 0 {
        ret["file"] = file
    }
    let ext = url.pathExtension
    if ext.count > 0 {
        ret["extension"] = ext
    }
    let path = url.deletingLastPathComponent().path
    if path.count > 0 {
        ret["path"] = path
    }
```

I called this in my test case thus...

```
ParseVideoFilename.parse("non-empty-filename.m4v")
```

And this is what resulted:

```
["ext": "m4v", "file": "non-empty-filename", "path": "/private/tmp"]
```

I am a bit surprised about that path. I did not pass that in, so I assume URL is doing something here. I don't expand the path nor resolve it. Is this expected behavior, and if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Running your code in a playground just gave me `file:///private/var/folders/1p/wpwdypm96_s5zfwxxzvwwp0m0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.Playground-C18F0418-5C1D-4772-9AE9-E3EF9AA2F07C/non-empty-filename.m4v` as the output of

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filename)
print(url.absoluteString)
```

This looks to me as the current directory of the process that gets executed by Playground. I'm not at all surprised by this, since we gave `URL` a relative path without any base and the `file` URI scheme doesn't really know how to handle relative paths (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15193744/1918561))

If you absolutely don't want to see these artifacts, you can modify your parser to use an absolute path:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/" + filename)
print(url.absoluteString) // prints "file:///non-empty-filename.m4v"
```

Comment: Most excellent!

Comment: So on my machine under a playground the path is / even without the extra "/". This is also not ideal. I think I'll just remove it, it was only informational anyway.